# ELC AL-901 Bench power supply

Tags: power-supply, power

what is the role of ic-1A, and D2-D3,
if the voltage variation is made by R11-R12, and the current regulation is made by ic-1B
thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: It looks like some kind of fold-back current limiting. R1 is a current sensing resistor. As the load current increases, ic-1B activates first, reducing the drive to the pass transistors. But if the load current increases further, ic-1A is also activated. Without knowing what the main regulator chip is, it's impossible to say more. It says "723", but the pinout doesn't match any of the packages of the [LM723](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm723.pdf).

Comment: This is a µA723 sold at the time by SGS-ATES, before it became STM. You can see the pinout on page 186 of this scanned [data-book](https://www.rsp-italy.it/Electronics/Databooks/SGS/_contents/SGS%20Voltage%20Regulators%20Op%20Amps%20&%20Comparators%201983.pdf). The ORed op-amps will bias an internal transistor which reduces the base current of the series-pass transistor \$Q_1\$. IC-1A features a 2.2-ms time constant, like if it's current-limit function had to be delayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a power supply manufactured by [ELC](https://elc.fr/en/), a French company, still in business in Haute-Savoie. The data-sheet is [here](https://nsa38.casimages.com/img/2016/07/09/160709060835302725.jpg).

[image]

The part that they used is a µA723, supposedly designed by the legendary Bob Widlar (see this [site](https://boldport.com/blog/bob-widlar-723)). SGS did release its own version, the L123 (low voltage) and the L146 (high voltage). You can find the specs of these old components - plus that of the µA723 - in the pages of this scanned [data-book](https://www.rsp-italy.it/Electronics/Databooks/SGS/_contents/SGS%20Voltage%20Regulators%20Op%20Amps%20&%20Comparators%201983.pdf).

I ran a quick simulation of this circuit and it is not exactly a constant-current regulator but more a kind of two-step current-limit which reduces the bias current of the external series-pass Darlington:

[image]

When the current increases and exceeds the 4-A limit, the power supply starts breaking by biasing the internal bipolar inside the 723. This is the one connected between pins 2 and 3 which, when it conducts, squeezes the Darlington base-emitter bias. It is IC1A who features a higher gain than 1B who increases quickly but in a delayed way so that if there is a transient load, it does not collapse the output prematurely. Because of the two 1N4148 clamping diodes, the action of IC1A is kind of limited in amplitude: it starts biasing the transistor but not completely. Then, if the current keeps increasing, it is 1B that finishes the job and further biases the internal bipolar to block the Darlington bias. Without these two diodes, 1A would immediately clamp the output current.

This is my interpretation and I might be wrong of course but it looks like a kind of 2-step current break where a first one gently limits the current (IC1A with its clamping diodes) whereas the second op-amp (IC1B) truly hard-brakes if a short circuit happens. Let me know what you think.

Comment: thank you, it's very detailed